# Java code running in Tomcat WebApp runs much slower than when invoked from JVM

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, web-applications

I have a java class that parses a file to gather information. Using a test file of about 8 MB, it completes in about 250 ms when running it within a test java program. When I integrate this class into a Tomcat webapp (a restful web service), parsing the same file takes about 5-10 seconds.

Any pointers on where to look first?

Comment: Does that time include tomcat startup? Where is the parsing done?

Comment: Tomcat has already started when the code is invoked. I'm uploading the file to the server using a web service.

Comment: And have you looked at whether this is CPU blocked or IO blocked?

Comment: @Doug: If one case is dealing with a file that's being uploaded over the network, and another case is dealing with a file on a local disk, I don't think they're really comparable.

Comment: After the file is uploaded to the web service, the java class that parses the file is called. This call takes 5-10 seconds within the web service. Calling the same method on the same class using the same input file takes 250 ms in the test java program (outside of tomcat + web service)

Comment: Is Tomcat doing anything else during this time, handling other requests? Are you running both scenarios on the same machine?

Comment: @Jon, I know what you mean. However, I'm debugging this in Eclipse (running Tomcat in Eclipse using instructions from this link http://eclipse.dzone.com/tips/launching-and-debugging-tomcat). The slowness occurs just in the call to the parse method...the file is already uploaded and in a temp directory.

Comment: @Doug: Well if you're running under a debugger, that could seriously be affecting the performance too...

Comment: How are you timing it? Can we see some code?

Comment: Thanks, all. The slowness only occurred when stepping through the code during debugging. When no breakpoints were set, the parse times were comparable. Thanks for the suggestions!